# How to push image (behind canvas) to front in order for its onclick function to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I have image of a pawn on a board.
The image has `onclick` function that when you press on it you **should** recive an alert.
The problem is that above the image there is canvas that hides the functionality of the `onclick`.

When I put the mouse mouse cursor (using Chrome's magnifying galss) you can see that the canvas is on top of the pawn's images:
[image]

**With canvas:**
[JSFIDDLE: when click pawn nothing happens](http://jsfiddle.net/La292q67/2/)

**Without canvas:**
[JSFIDDLE: when click pawn receive alert](http://jsfiddle.net/1zrw5ro2/2/)

How can I keep the canvas and push the pawn image to front in order for the `onclick` function to work?

**CSS:**

```
td {
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
table
{
    position: fixed;
    left:9px;
    top:8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd), tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even)
{
    background:#00A2E8;
}

td span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

#myCanvas {
    z-index: 10;
    position:absolute;
    font:bold;
    color:red;

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>

<div id="board" value="5">

<table oncontextmenu="return false">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="" cellnumber="21" row="4" col="0"><span>21</span></td>
        <td class="" cellnumber="22" row="4" col="1"><span>22</span>
        <br><br><p class="SnakesAndLadders" from="22" to="6">Snake to 6 </p></td>
        <td class="" cellnumber="23" row="4" col="2"><span>23</span></td>
        <td class="" cellnumber="24" row="4" col="3"><span>24</span></td>
        <td class="" cellnumber="25" row="4" col="4"><span>25</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
     <td class="" cellnumber="16" row="3" col="0"><span>16</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="17" row="3" col="1"><span>17</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="18" row="3" col="2"><span>18</span></td>
      <td class="" cellnumber="19" row="3" col="3"><span>19</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="20" row="3" col="4"><span>20</span></td></tr>
     <tr>
     <td class="" cellnumber="11" row="2" col="0"><span>11</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="12" row="2" col="1"><span>12</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="13" row="2" col="2"><span>13</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="14" row="2" col="3"><span>14</span></td>
     <td class="" cellnumber="15" row="2" col="4"><span>15</span>
     <br><br><p class="SnakesAndLadders" from="15" to="24">Ladder to 24 </p>
     </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td class="" cellnumber="6" row="1" col="0"><span>6</span></td>
    <td class="" cellnumber="7" row="1" col="1"><span>7</span></td>
    <td class="" cellnumber="8" row="1" col="2"><span>8</span></td>
    <td class="" cellnumber="9" row="1" col="3"><span>9</span></td>
    <td class="" cellnumber="10" row="1" col="4"><span>10</span></td>
               </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="" cellnumber="1" row="0" col="0"><span>1</span>
                         <img src = "http://s23.postimg.org/ynlvim1x3/image.png" onclick="doSomething()">
                 </td>
    <td class="" cellnumber="2" row="0" col="1"><span>2</span></td>
    <td class="" cellnumber="3" row="0" col="2"><span>3</span></td>
    <td class="" cellnumber="4" row="0" col="3"><span>4</span></td>
    <td class="" cellnumber="5" row="0" col="4"><span>5</span></td>
                 </tr>

                </table>
     <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
     <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="600" height="500"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(50, 45);
      context.lineTo(500, 450);
      context.stroke();
      context.stroke();

      function doSomething()
       {
         alert("Ping");
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the canvas is doing nothing other than drawing lines, then just tell the browser not to listen for events on the canvas:

```
#myCanvas{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/La292q67/5/

Answer (score 1):

Like this? `jsfiddle.net/hrLo5a3b/`

Just moved canvas out of the table and removed z-index. Looks like your example but pawn reacts on alert.

EDIT (Can't make comments yet so will put it here in my post):

Don't forget that `pointer-events` does not work in IE 10 and earlier versions. Also does not work on links in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using z-index (CSS property). Set the element with the onclick as z-index:2 and the canvas as z-index:1.

This only works on positioned elements though, so you'll have to work with that.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a position and z-index on the imnage http://jsfiddle.net/La292q67/3/

for the image I add class .pingit

```
.pingit{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

Comment: your example doesn't work: when I click the pawn, nothing happens.

Comment: HOw do you need your elements to be ordered? Table, canvas, canvas? Does it matters who is on top of who?

Comment: The canvas should be on the table because otherwise we won't see the lines of the canvase.

Comment: If the canvas is on top of the table, and the table is the parent of the pawn image, than the image will never be on top of the canvas. You should think of another way to add the pawn image